# Cant get the template from DB

Tags: python, django, sql-server-2008

There is a database (Sql server 2008). I have a table SetDocsPrj that stores .doc templates. In this table, the template is in the Doc column in format image. How to get text from this field image and write it to a file?
doing so:

```
Text_in=Setdocsprj.objects.all()
res1=Text_in.filter(name=u'Template name')
for j in res1:
    t=j.doc
f1=open('test_gen.txt',"w")
f1.write(t)
f1.close()
```

Receive a file that records the binary code.
How to convert this binary code and write to the file?

Comment: there is no error.i receive a txt file with binary code inside.i want to convert binary to normal text

Comment: this isnt my DB. this is DB from C# project.there are files in doc format inside DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is :

```
Text_in=Setdocsprj.objects.all()
res1=Text_in.filter(name=u'Template name')
f1=open('test_gen.txt',"wb")
for j in res1:
    t=j.doc
    f1.write(t)
f1.close()
```